# Make button narrower instead of having it fill up entire screen horizontally

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have this button on this webpage which looks weirdly long. Here it is below;

[image]

I am using angularjs v1 materials.

The html code for my webpage is as follows;

```
<md-card>
    <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-text>
            <span class="md-headline">Room settings</span>
        </md-card-title-text>
    </md-card-title>
    <md-card-content>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
            <span>Room</span>
            <md-select ng-model="mode" placeholder="Mode1" class="md-no-underline">
                <md-option value="auto">Mode1</md-option>
                <md-option value="manual">Mode2</md-option>
            </md-select>
            <md-select ng-model="channel_number" placeholder="1" class="md-no-underline">
                <md-option value="1">1</md-option>
                <md-option value="2">2</md-option>
                <md-option value="3">3</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </div>
    </md-card-content>

    <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="Process()">Button Press</md-button>
<md-card>
```

I want to narrow the width of this button to look like a normal button. I have used similar code like `<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="Process()">Button Press</md-button>` elsewhere and I do not see this elongated button there except on this webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is filling its container `<md-card>`, try putting it inside another container, the recommendation in the demos is md-card-actions:

```
<md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
  <md-button>Action 1</md-button>
  <md-button>Action 2</md-button>
</md-card-actions>
```

Check out the Card action demo in:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/card